# How to filter BLE devices that are advertising extended advertising message?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have implemented the following BLE scan callback,

```
private final ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onScanResult: " +result.toString());
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            if (result.getDevice().getName() != null && getString(R.string.unknown_device_text).compareTo(result.getDevice().getName().toLowerCase()) != 0) {
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(result.getDevice());
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onBatchScanResults: " +results.toString());
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onScanFailed: errorCode: " +errorCode);
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
    }
};
```

However, in this callback I am not getting BLE devices that are advertising extended message. In contrast, in same place nRF app shows extended devices in their list.

Here is my scan method,

```
private void scanLeDevice() {

    List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    ScanFilter.Builder scanFilterBuilder = new ScanFilter.Builder();
    filters.add(scanFilterBuilder.build());

    ScanSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
    settingsBuilder.setPhy(ScanSettings.PHY_LE_ALL_SUPPORTED);

    final BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            Log.d(TAG, "scanLeDevice stopScan called");
        }
    }, SCAN_PERIOD);            

    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settingsBuilder.build(), mScanCallback);
}
```

So, how can I filter and find the devices with extended advertising capabilities.

Comment: I assume you are running both apps on the same hardware. Which [ScanSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings) do you use? Have you set [PHY_LE_ALL_SUPPORTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings#PHY_LE_ALL_SUPPORTED)

Comment: @Risto Yes both apps in same device, Galaxy Flip4. I also added my scan method. No luck even with scan settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to show extended advertisements, you need to use the **setLegacy(false)** method. By default this is set to **true**, which is why you need to change it when setting up your scan settings.

Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [ScanSettings.Builder setLegacy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder#setLegacy(boolean))
- [How to scan Bluetooth 5 extended advertising with Pixel 3a](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/54651/how-to-scan-bluetooth-5-extended-advertising-from-nrf52840-with-pixel-3a)

UPDATE

You can filter **only** BLE devices that are doing extended adverts by checking the advert type. You can access the advert type by reading the [scanRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord) (e.g. using the [getBytes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord#getBytes()) method). You can read further on how to read the advert type [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102854/ble-advertising-rawdata-how-to-decode/62126301#62126301) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003777/read-advertisement-packet-in-android). Legacy adverts will be one of the following 4 types:-

1. ADV_IND
2. ADV_DIRECT_IND
3. ADV_NONCONN_IND
4. ADV_SCAN_IND

While extended adverts will be one of the following 4 types:

1. ADV_EXT_IND
2. AUX_ADV_IND
3. AUX_SYNC_IND
4. AUX_CHAIN_IND

This can be see in more details in the table below:-

[image]

Below are some other useful links on understanding the meaning of advert packets:-

- [Bluetooth 5 adverts: Everything you need to know](https://novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-advertisements/)
- [How do iBeacons work](https://www.warski.org/blog/2014/01/how-ibeacons-work/)
- [BLE advertising primer](https://www.argenox.com/library/bluetooth-low-energy/ble-advertising-primer/)